# Spring Boot not failing when property is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I make Spring-Boot fail during startup if any of the properties of a `@ConfigurationProperties` class is missing?

If I use `@Value(...)` instead, the auto-wiring fails as expected, but I want to centralise all properties into a `@ConfigurationProperties` class instead of using `@Value` references spread through the application.

The code:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "serving.api", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private String projectId;

    private String bigTableInstanceId;

    public String getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public String getBigTableInstanceId() {
        return bigTableInstanceId;
    }

    public void setBigTableInstanceId(String bigTableInstanceId) {
        this.bigTableInstanceId = bigTableInstanceId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `@NotNull` validator to your mandatory properties. For example:

```
@NotNull
private String projectId;

public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}
```